# Monitor network shared folder

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to monitor a network shared folder using filesystemwatcher. Using windows form I can monitor the folder, but using windows service, I could not. Both my PC and the network shared folder is not in a domain. Is there anything I need to do to monitor the folder through windows service?

Comment: Which security account do you use for your windows service? Is it "local system", "local service" or "network service"? I had some problem before with shared folders until I start use "network service" account.

Comment: Even with network service, I still could not monitor the folder. My code for setting the path is as follows:

    fileSystemWatcher.Path = "//192.168.1.10/FileServer/External";

Comment: how do you connect to the network share?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a UNC path name.

> fileSystemWatcher.Path = @"\192.168.1.10\FileServer\External";

Comment: I have used the filesystemwacher to monitor a local folder instead since I do not need to monitor a network folder.